No 3 vectors independent over $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, without AoC

Q: Are there three $\mathbb{Z}^2$ vectors independent over $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Context: This problem arise naturally when I'm characterizing possible sub-"latice" in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Formally let $S$ be a set of points ("lattice points") with integer coordinates, and a set of vectors $V = \{ v_1, v_2, ...\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2$ so that for all $p \in S$ and $v \in V$, $$p \pm v \in S.$$ i.e., is also a lattice point.
We can make a hexagon-like lattice by choosing $(v_1, v_2, v_3) = ((2, 1), (2, -1), (0, 2))$. Notice, then, $v_1 - v_2 = v_3$, so $v_3$ is redundant in $V$- so we can remove $v_3$ while keeping the set $S$. So we ask: is the third vector always redundant, in the sense that
$$ cv_3 = av_1+bv_2, a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z} \implies a=b=c=0?$$

A quick search of "L.I. over $\mathbb{Z}$" reveals that in $\mathbb{Z}^n$, linear independence over $\mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$. This overkills the question: if there were 3 independent vectors over $\mathbb{Z}$, then they are too in $\mathbb{R}$, a contradiction.
However, the prove involves using the basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ to deal with the real coefficients, which is a implication of Axiom of Choice. Since my question is simple enough, I would like to see if there is a proof without AoC.

Q: Is the negation of "there exists three $\mathbb{Z}^2$ vectors independent over $\mathbb{Z}$" provable without AoC?


You don't need to go to $\mathbb{R}$. They are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$, and you can then clear denominators.

The usual row-reduction method of solving systems of linear equations should produce a nontrivial rational linear combination of them that vanishes, and then clear denominators as @ArturoMagidin says to find an integer linear combination.

Naive question:  doesn’t a vector space (unlike a module) have to be over a field, which $\mathbb Z$ is not?

@J.W.Tanner in general you want a vector space to be over a field but since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain we can construct its field of fractions so many results are easier in this special case.

@J.W.Tanner You are correct that technically we shouldn't call them "vectors" (since they are not elements of a vector space); but it seems like there is little harm to do so here.

I don't see where the proof you linked needs the axiom of choice. At one point we take a basis of $X$, which is a subset of $\Bbb R$, but since it's a finite-dimensional vector space, taking a basis does not require AC.

@IzaakvanDongen I see. Yes, it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but finitely generated over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I think you could have similar results replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ by an integral commutative ring, and finite rank free $A$-modules? Tensoring by its field of fractions would work the same way (or at least I believe)

Any three elements in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ are also three vectors in $\mathbb{Q}^2$. But $\mathbb{Q}^2$ has dimension $2$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space (no need for the Axiom of Choice, as $\mathbb{Q}^2$ has an explicit finite generating set over $\mathbb{Q}$).
That means that if $(a_1,b_1)$, $(a_2,b_2)$, and $(a_3,b_3)$ are in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, then there exist rational numbers $\frac{r_1}{s_1}$, $\frac{r_2}{s_2}$, $\frac{r_3}{s_3}$, not all zero, $s_i\neq 0$, such that
$$\frac{r_1}{s_1}(a_1,b_1) + \frac{r_2}{s_2}(a_2,b_2) + \frac{r_3}{s_3}(a_3,b_3) = (0,0).$$
Multiplying through by the nonzero element $s_1s_2s_3$, we obtain a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination equal to $(0,0)$. Since $s_1s_2s_3\neq 0$ and not all of $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_3$ are zero, at least one of the coefficients in
$$r_1s_2s_3(a_1,b_1) + r_2s_1s_3(a_2,b_2) + r_3s_1s_2(a_3,b_3) = (0,0)$$
is nonzero, proving that the three elements are $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly dependent.

Clear, simple :)

Let your vectors be the columns of the matrix
$$\left( \begin{matrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
                  b_1 & b_2 & b_3
  \end{matrix}\right)$$
denote its rows by $a$, and $b$. We have $\langle a, a\times b \rangle = \langle b, a \times b\rangle = 0$.  If $a\times b\ne 0$, we got a $0$ linear combination of the columns ( with coefficients the components of $a\times b$).   Assume now $a\times b = 0$.  Now  we have $-a_2 b_1 + a_1 b_2 = 0$. Note that we also have trivially $-a_2 a_1 + a_1 a_2 = 0$, so we get
$$-a_2 c_1 + a_1 c_2 = 0$$
where $c_1$, $c_2$ are the first two columns.  Of course, if $a_1= a_2=0$, this is a trivial linear combination, but such a situation can be easily dealt with.
